# ValidatePatternAttribute accepting invalid input

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script in a file "Publish-MyProj.ps1" with a header defined like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidatePattern("\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}")]
    [string]$Version
)
```

When I run the script like this:

```
.\Publish-MyProj.ps1 10.2
```

It shows an error, which is an expected behaviour.

However, when I run it with an almost alright version:

```
.\Publish-MyProj.ps1 111.2.25
```

It does not fail, even though the first number exceeds the number of allowed digits.

Is it a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've not specified your regex to match from beginning of the string, so it matches 1**11.2.25** and doesn't fail.

Use this regex (note `^` modifer): `^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}`

Or even better: `^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}$`

P.S. You can easily test your regex at https://regex101.com and see what matches and not.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/aD8xU2/1

Comment: I am trying to learn powershell, so I have completely missed this rookie mistake while my mind was elsewhere.

Comment: @Santhos I think we all had those moments :).